# Getting text to vertically line up within text input field

Tags: html, css, forms, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation 6 framework to construct my pages. I have a separate style sheet called effects.css that I use to customize text and tables and inputs and such.

I actually have to style it, because without the custom styles the input fields are huge and grotesque. Must be some scaled styles in the foundation.css that are responsible.

I made a short, thin text input field, but the text inside doesn't seem to want to vertically line up correctly. The cursor blinks up and sort of half way out of the white text area.

Here's the html:

```
<form name="quick-connect" id="quick-connect" method="post" action="/ajax/quick-connect-action/" onsubmit="return false;">
    <span class="med-text white-text">Your name:</span><input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="small-input" />
    <span class="med-text white-text">Your phone #:</span><input type="text" name="number" id="number" class="small-input" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="quick-connect-submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="LCHG" />
</form>
```

Here's my attempt at css'ing the input fields:

```
input.small-input{
    width:10em;
    height:1em;
    line-height:1em;
    font-size:.9em;
    color:#000;
}
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: text input with cursor up too high]

The blinking text cursor isn't vertically align within the text field.

Comment: You must have something else altering it. I don't see any reason why that would be happening based upon your posted markup/CSS. --https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/p5kvzxgx/

Comment: The code you provided does not seem to have the issue you are describing: https://jsfiddle.net/yek8yq2v/

Comment: @Scott Your fiddle validates your assertion.

Comment: @Scott It was the padding. I set `padding:0;` and it corrected.

Comment: @APAD1 There must be a style in another stylesheet that adds padding to text inputs. Set padding to 0 and the text lines up vertically just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a padding problem. I set the padding to 0 within the input style, and the text properly vertically aligns now.

```
input.small-input{
    width:10em;
    height:2em;
    line-height:2em;
    font-size:.8em;
    color:#000;
    padding:0;
}
```